# AG Grid agRichSelectCellEditor - how to validate if pasted value is in provided options

Tags: reactjs, validation, drop-down-menu, ag-grid

I'm using AG Grid v. 25, React and I have this colDef.

```
{
    headerName: item.name,
    field: item.name,              
    cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',               
    cellEditorParams: {
    values: item.options,                   
      },
}
```

I want to validate if a value which is pasted into cell is oincluded in item.options.

What I have tried:

1. `valueSetter` doesn't allow me to choose any option. If I click on a value in dropdown, cell is still empty

```
 valueSetter: function (params: any) {                   
                    const enteredValue = params.newValue;
                    const validValues = params.colDef.cellEditorParams.values;
                    
                    if (!validValues.includes(enteredValue)) {
                            return '';
                    }
                    return true;
                },
```

2. `onCellValueChanged` works correctly for normal behavior but doesn't restrict pasting whatever I want

```
 onCellValueChanged: function (params: any) {
                    const enteredValue = params.newValue;
                    const validValues = params.colDef.cellEditorParams.values;
                    const currentCellValue = params.data[params.colDef.field];
                 
                    if (!validValues.includes(enteredValue)) {                      
                        if (currentCellValue !== currentCellValue) {
                            params.node.setDataValue(params.colDef.field, '')
                        }
                    }
                },
```

3. `valueParser` - similar to 2.

```
valueParser: function (params: any) {
                    const enteredValue = params.newValue;
                    const validValues = params.colDef.cellEditorParams.values;

                    if (validValues?.indexOf(enteredValue) !== -1) {
                        return enteredValue;
                    }
                    return undefined
                },
```

4. `processDataFromClipboard` / `processCellFromClipboard` - these are not even called when pasting

```
    processDataFromClipboard: function (params: any) {
                    const clipBoardData = params.value;
                    const validValues = params.colDef.cellEditorParams.values;
                  
                    if (validValues?.indexOf(clipBoardData) !== -1) {

                        return clipBoardData
                    } return ''

                },
```